# Simulation of Monte Carlo test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, simulation, monte-carlo, statistical-power

Using R, I am trying to simulate how the power of a Monte Carlo two-sample test for central tendency changes with sample size. **However, my simulation results does not show power increasing with sample size which is clearly wrong.**

**Could someone please advise where I am going wrong?** Below is the basic set-up.

The null hypothesis is:

$H_0=\mu_X-\mu_Y=0$

The alternative hypothesis is:

$H_1=\mu_X>\mu_Y=0$

The test statistic is:

$E(x)-E(y)$

For my simulation, I use two samples $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_y)$, $Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y)$ of size $n_X$ and $n_Y$ respectively. I run 100 simulations for every increase in the sample size of X.

Below is my coded simulation with comments:

```
 mc.pvalue<-function(nx, ny, mu.x, mu.y, sig.x, sig.y){
    x<-rnorm(nx, mu.y, sig.x)            # Generate samples under H1: mu_x > mu_y
    y<-rnorm(ny, mu.x, sig.y)            
    obs.diff<-mean(x)-mean(y)            # Test-stat is observed diff. in means 
    se.x<-sd(x)/sqrt((length(x)))        # Calculate standard errors 
    se.y<-sd(y)/sqrt((length(y)))
    count=0                              # Set counter equal to zero
    for(i in 1:1000){                    # Generate 1000 pairs of samples and calculate
      x1<-rnorm(nx, mu.y, se.x)          # the difference in means between each pair.
      y1<-rnorm(ny, mu.y, se.y)          # The samples have been generated under
      sim.diff<-mean(x1)-mean(y1)        # H0: mu_x = mu_y
      if(sim.diff<= obs.diff){count=count+1} 
    }
    count/1000                           # Estimated p-value for test statistic
}


# Calculate 100 estimated p-values for the test statistic. Then find the proportion of times
# reject hypothesis at level of significance 0.05

calc.pvalues<-function(nx, ny=10, mu.x=21, mu.y=20, sig.x=0.5, sig.y=0.25, 
                    n.sim=100){ 
  pvalues<-replicate(n.sim, mc.pvalue(nx, ny, sig.x, sig.y, mu.x, mu.y))
  sum(pvalues<0.05)/n.sim  
}

chge.sample.size<-seq(2, 100, by=0.05)          # Sample size x increasing from 1 to 100
result<-sapply(chge.sample.size, calc.pvalues)  # Apply the calc.pvalues function to
                                                # estimate p-value for each sample size
                                                # of x    
plot(chge.sample.size, result)                  # Plot increasing sample size of X 
                                                # against test power
```

When I an edit the code to calculate the power of a t-test, it works perfectly:

```
calc.pvalue.t<-function(nx, ny, sig.x, sig.y, mu.x, mu.y){    
  x<-rnorm(nx, mu.x, sig.x)
  y<-rnorm(ny, mu.y, sig.y)
  t.test(x, y, alternative="greater", 
         paired=FALSE, conf.level=0.95)$p.value
}

calc.t<-function(nx, ny=10, mu.x=21, mu.y=20, sig.x=0.5, sig.y=0.25, 
                    n.sim=100, alpha=0.05){
  p.values<-replicate(n.sim, calc.pvalue.t(nx, ny, sig.x, 
                                            sig.y, mu.x, mu.y))
  sum(p.values<alpha)/n.sim  
}

chge.sample.size<-seq(2, 10, by=1)
tpower1<-sapply(chge.sample.size, calc.t)

plot(chge.sample.size, tpower1)
```

**Something seems to be going wrong with the first part of my code when I try to do the Monte Carlo test**

Comment: I thought that if you assumed H1 was true when generating the data, the above calculations give power. Assuming H0 is true gives size?

Comment: I don't think your mc.pvalue function does anything meaningful.  (By the way, the variable cnt is not defined -- you mean count, right?)

Comment: As written, mc.pvalue(100, 100, 10, 50, 1, 1) will always return 1.  What does that mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry I have changed it to count.

Comment: That the probability of getting a test statistic at least as large as the one observed is 1.

Comment: You use `mu.y` (not `mu.x`) to generate `x` and `mu.x` to generate `y`, is this what you want?

Comment: Under H0, mu.y=mu.x=20
Under H1, mx.y=20 < mx.x=21

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the reason is that the empirical distribution is changed with every observation in the function "mc.pvalue". So the 100 p-values are calculated with different empirical distribution.

Comment: Could you expand on this and perhaps provide an alternative code. As it stands this is not a complete answer. Please see these guidelines for a good answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer